# WSGI and Sigterm (Falcon)

Tags: wsgi, gunicorn, falconframework

I'm using Falcon (wsgi) web server, and I want to make sure that if a sigterm is received by the application, that the application will finish all of the current HTTP requests before exiting (and not accept any more new ones)

I'm running with gunicorn.

It doesn't appear that Falcon does this  - I set up a test middleware that loops a bunch to simulate a lot of work, then I write to a file at the end of it. If I <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in the middle it looks like it doesn't finish the request before exiting.

Is there some flag with gunicorn or some setting with Falcon that I need to apply for it to act with this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out I had a bug with my test. It looks like SIGTERM is handled gracefully as expected.